# Is it possible to display a DialogFragment in a master-detail arragement without a new activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, master-detail, android-actionbar-compat

I'm looking for a way to display a DialogFragment in single-pane mode without creating a new activity.

I originally set up a DialogFragment as a popup dialog in my Android app, with the intent to eventually pursue the master-detail pattern for larger devices.

However, now that I'm looking to finally implement the master-detail setup I'm running into all sorts of UI complications.  Basically, I'd like to have something like a 'contextual action mode' update to the action bar.  That requires some planning in two-pane mode, but it doesn't work at all with a popup dialog (unless I'm missing some way to show the action bar and the popup dialog).

I'd rather not create a new activity to house the detail DialogFragment on non-tablet/large devices, since there is a lot of DB-related code in the existing activity.  However, I have trouble just doing FragmentTransaction.replace because the main view is based on a modified FragmentTabsPager from the compatibility lib v4 demo.  I don't have a fragment to replace, unless I wrap the entire pager in a fragment - and I'm worried that nesting fragments is a hack that will complicate, rather simplify things in the long run.  Am I wrong?

I'm also using ActionBarCompat, which complicates things as there are some UI options that aren't ported.  I'd consider going API 11+ if it meant finding a clean solution to this.

BTW I'm starting to look at Commonsware's master-detail library, but it's a bit of code to grok and ingest, and I think it would require a few possibly big changes to make my code compatible.

Any suggestions or comments?  I think I'm too close to this one to see how to simplify it...

Comment: Instead of displaying DialogFragment as dialog, do you want to show DialogFragment content inside an Activity i.e. displayed as part of Activity's view hierarchy? In that case, you can use [DialogFragment.setShowsDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setShowsDialog(boolean)) method. I've shared sample app in [gist](https://gist.github.com/manishcm/63fdfa30bb74eca662d8).

Comment: Yes Manish - that is the basic concept and your example works in a normal case.  However, in my case I have a viewpager (based on FragmentTabsPager) which makes it difficult to use FragmentTransaction -- the view to remove/hide isn't currently a fragment, it's a tabhost (which includes fragments).  Doing replace just overlaps the content since there was no fragment to remove.  It's looking like I have to nest fragments to turn my top-level tabhost into a fragment, then FragmentTransaction.replace should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

This is the XML of the layout of your Activity.
What you need to do is enclose all your activity content in a layout (like i have done here in id = all_activity_content_id).

Now put two more views in the activity:- A RelativeLayout for your dialog and a View for making the background translucent.

Note: Make sure the root layout of your activity is a RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.curium.testandroid.MainActivity" >

<!-- all your activity's existing code goes here -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/all_activity_content_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle_dialog_box_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textOff="@string/show_dialog"
        android:textOn="@string/hide_dialog" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- translucent black background behind the dialog -->

<View
    android:id="@+id/black_layer_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:alpha="0.6"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- your dialog layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog_id"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#00BFFF"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="@string/dialog_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_title_id"
        android:text="@string/dialog_description" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity class add two methods to show and hide the dialog layout.
Override the back button to dismiss the dialog when visible otherwise call super.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_dialog_box_id);
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View toggleB) {
            boolean isOn = ((ToggleButton) toggleB).isChecked();
            if (isOn) {
                showDialog();
            } else {
                hideDialog();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showDialog() {
    View opaqueBackground = findViewById(R.id.black_layer_id);
    RelativeLayout dialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dialog_id);
    opaqueBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void hideDialog() {
    View opaqueBackground = findViewById(R.id.black_layer_id);
    RelativeLayout dialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dialog_id);
    opaqueBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    dialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ToggleButton toggleB = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_dialog_box_id);
    boolean isOn = toggleB.isChecked();
    if (isOn) {
        toggleB.setChecked(false);
        hideDialog();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}}
```

Now any code that you want to put in the dialog will have access to the database adapter that you have in the activity.

Positioning the dialog in the center of your detail fragment will be a bit tricky.

Hope this helps.

Source Code: https://github.com/testv200/DialogInsideAcitvity

Comment: This may be the best way to work with the combination of issues I mentioned.  Just hiding the view may have other consequences, but it solves the problem of not being able to remove the visible content (just hide it).  I would need to replace one of the layouts with a container to hold fragments, and add some code to handle fragment management to make this work.  It's a good path to investigate though, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

(1) You should definitely not have to create an entire new Activity whose sole purpose is to house a new `DialogFragment`. If you are going to create a new activity at all, you might as well just give it a dialog-theme and display that as your dialog instead... that would eliminate the need to show a `DialogFragment` entirely.

(2) Your question is a bit too general for me to give a confident answer... you mention "contextual action mode", "dialog fragment", "fragment tabs pager", "nested fragments", etc. and I'm not sure how it all fits together or what specifically you are trying to achieve. What I do know is that no matter the configuration, the host activity should always be the one in charge of performing fragment transactions (such as showing a `DialogFragment`) as this will significantly reduce code complexity (especially when the number of fragments displayed on the screen varies depending on the screen size). Do your fragments communicate with the activity via activity callback methods (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface))? Where in your code do you show the `DialogFragment`: in your activity or in one of the master/detail fragments?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to be concise and clear here...  I have a tabbed interface which loads three fragment tabs. Two of those tabs are ListFragment (which would make them master), and upon click they load a DialogFragment (the detail, currently as a popup).  A FragmentTransaction is used to show the DialogFragment from within the ListFragment.  Both the master and detail fragments use getActivity() to communicate with the main activity (primarily to get the database adapter).  I'd like to be able to see and use the action bar while showing the detail view, which would enable the action mode.

Comment: to me it sounds like he want the `DialogFragment` to appear inside the space that a particular fragment is being displayed instead of appearing in the center of the screen like it should, which IMO is a terrible idea

Comment: I might indeed be mashing up UI concepts in a way that will become awkward. However, think of it like the master/detail pattern which IS considered good practice. It puts the detail (which is now in a DialogFragment) as a fragment in a new activity just for that fragment. It behaves like a dialog to the user in this case, but is certainly not centered in the screen - it replaces the entire view.  I'm attempting to perform the SAME UI as the master/detail pattern, but making the mechanics different underneath, and displaying the fragment in the same activity rather than creating a new activity.

Comment: The Master and the Detail could simply be **2 Fragments in the same Activity** (one ontop of the other in portrait and one close to the other in landscape). I don't see the need for a DialogFragment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible Because you are using Activity

If you extends FragmentActivity than it's only possible because if you want to show DialogFragment than it's required FragmentManager reference it's not possible in normal Activity. It's provide only inside FragmentActivity or above API level 13

Comment: I am using ActionBarActivity from the v7 compatibility library, not the explicit Activity class.

Answer (score 1):

**This is my DialogFragment class**

public class DetailedFragment extends DialogFragment {

```
private static final String ARG_SHOW_AS_DIALOG = "DetailedFragment.ARG_SHOW_AS_DIALOG";

public static DetailedFragment newInstance(boolean showAsDialog) {
    DetailedFragment fragment = new DetailedFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean(ARG_SHOW_AS_DIALOG, showAsDialog);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public static DetailedFragment newInstance() {
    return newInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        setShowsDialog(args.getBoolean(ARG_SHOW_AS_DIALOG, true));
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailed_fragment, container, false);
}
```

}

Comment: I did work with setShowsDialog, but one big complication here is the code outside of the fragment, needed to call up the Fragment in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**This is my ActionBarActivity Class**

**This is the code for showing Dialog inside ActionBarActivity class.I think Please check your import statements**

public class DetailedActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detailed_activity);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        DetailedFragment fragment = DetailedFragment.newInstance(false);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.root_layout_details, fragment, "Some_tag").commit();
    }
}
```

}